# Literature Recommendation - Classical Electromagnetic Scattering Theory

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, scattering, education

I'd like to ask for your recommendation on literature regarding classical electromagnetic scattering at an introductory level.

The aim is understanding the mathematics behind simple scattering problems, namely by a cylindrical perfect electric conductor, which I plan to figure in my Master's Thesis.

Comment: There is a big list o book recommendations in https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175/ 
Might be a good place to start

Comment: I went in and checked Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics, and it seems to address the scattering of EM waves on a PEC sphere. I'll take a look at it tomorrow. Thanks for the quick answer. 

If you can think of any other suggestions let me know.

Comment: I'm just gonna leave this here for anybody who finds it helpful in the future. What I was looking for is called Mie Theory.